# How do I solve questions pertaining to rate of disappearance and appearance?

Tags: kinetics, concentration

> In a reversible reaction $\ce{2NO2 <=>[$k_1$][$k_2$] N2O4}$, the rate of disappearance of $\ce{NO2}$ is equal to:
>
> 1. $2\frac{k_1}{k_2}\ce{[NO2]}^2$
> 2. $2k_1\ce{[NO2]}^2-2k_2\ce{[N2O4]}$
> 3. $2k_1\ce{[NO2]}^2-k_2\ce{[N2O4]}$
> 4. $(2k_1-k_2)\ce{[NO2]}$

The answer, they say, is (2). I just don't understand how they got it. I find it difficult to solve these questions. Is the rate of disappearance the derivative of the concentration of the reactant *divided by its coefficient in the reaction*, or is it simply the derivative?

If someone could help me with the solution, it would be great. And please, don't assume I'm just picking up a random question from a book and asking it for fun without actually trying to do it. I have worked at it and I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, if you have a system of elementary reactions, the rate of appearance of a species $\ce{A}$ will be

$$\cfrac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[A]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \sum\limits_i \nu_{\ce{A},i} r_i$$

where

- $i$ is each reaction in the system
- $\nu_{\ce{A},i}$ is the stoichiometric coefficient of species $\ce{A}$ in reaction $i$ (positive for products, negative for reagents)
- $r_i$ is the rate for reaction $i$, which in turn will be calculated as a product of concentrations for all reagents $j$ times the kinetic coefficient $k_i$:

$$r_i = k_i \prod\limits_{j} [j]^{\nu_{j,i}}$$

In other words, there's a positive contribution to the rate of appearance for each reaction in which $\ce{A}$ is produced, and a negative contribution to the rate of appearance for each reaction in which $\ce{A}$ is consumed, and these contributions are equal to the rate of that reaction times the stoichiometric coefficient.

The rate of disappearance will simply be *minus* the rate of appearance, so the signs of the contributions will be the opposite.

In your example, we have two elementary reactions:

$$\ce{2NO ->[$k_1$] N2O4} \tag{1}$$

$$\ce{N2O4 ->[$k_2$] 2NO} \tag{2}$$

So, the rate of *appearance* of $\ce{N2O4}$ would be

$$\cfrac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[N2O4]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = r_1 - r_2 $$

Similarly, the rate of *appearance* of $\ce{NO}$ would be

$$\cfrac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[NO]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = - 2 r_1 + 2 r_2$$

and the rate of *disappearance* of $\ce{NO}$ would be minus its rate of appearance:

$$-\cfrac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[NO]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = 2 r_1 - 2 r_2$$

Since the rates for both reactions would be

$$r_1 = k_1 \ce{[NO]}^2$$

$$r_2 = k_2 \ce{[N2O4]}$$

the rate of disappearance for $\ce{NO}$ will be

$$-\cfrac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[NO]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = 2 k_1 \ce{[NO]}^2 - 2 k_2 \ce{[N2O4]}$$